# Option to open folders in windows instead of tabs not working… Reset parameters?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

The option to open folders in windows instead of tabs is not working. I have been trying to figure out how to make this thing working again… Already activated-deactivated-activated-deactivated… the option in:

```
Finder --> Preferences --> Open folders in tabs instead of windows
```

And this thing isn't working, and I'm becoming kinda crazy because I don't like working with tabs. I already tried via terminal, killing all the .DS_store of the system and nothing seems to work.

Do you know if there's a hard reset?

*Just for the record: I'm trying this with a clean install of MacOS Mojave

Comment: Have you already tried trashing the com.apple.finder.plist (and sidebar.plist) in ~/Library/Preferences followed by a relogin/boot or killall Finder?

Comment: I could not find any .plist with the name "sidebar"… And I also found another two files located in:

com.apple.Finder.plist -->system -->library-->preferences-->logging-->subsystems

com.apple.Finder.plist --> system-->library-->launchagents

Not sure if I also need to delete these two?Thanks!

Comment: Only killing the com.apple.finder.plist is not working… :/